# Tkinter update Entry 6 each time a number gets typed in Entry 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a small and bad tkinter program to play MagicSquare where i have a 5x5 grid of Entry Boxes and at each end of rows and columns is a box which should count the sum of the row/column.
When you start the game some boxes are randomly filled with numbers. Now what i struggle with is anytime
the user types a number in a not yet filled Entry or retypes the number in the Entry the box which sums should get updated. I would like to know how to update without pressing any button or activating a function due to the numbers only getting typed in.

Thanks for the help!

I tried using another function as update_value() to .set() the stringvar() and then call the update_value() function inside the grid creation function

Here if a number randomly got assigned to Entry1 it gets taken into SumBox S1 but if it was empty and i type something into the Entry nothing happens so S1.

```py
def grid_insertion_5():
    global slots
    global v1
    global S1
    grid_data(5)
    frame_grid()
    print(data)

    slots = []
    for i in range(1,26):
        slots.append("E"+str(i))
    print(slots)
    pos = 0
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            insertion = data[i][j]
            if insertion != 0:
                slots[pos] = Entry(frame2, width=3, font="Arial 30")
                slots[pos].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=N + S + E + W, padx=5, pady=5)
                slots[pos].insert(0,insertion)
                slots[pos].config(state="readonly")
            else:
                slots[pos] = Entry(frame2, width=3, font="Arial 30",state=NORMAL)
                slots[pos].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=N + S + E + W, padx=5, pady=5)
            pos+=1
    v1 = StringVar()
    S1 = Entry(frame2,width=3, font="Arial 30", textvariable=v1)
    S1.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=5,pady=5)
    root.after(1, update_value)


def update_value():
    v1.set(slots[0].get())
    root.update()
```

```
    def test_example():
one_str = StringVar()
two_str = StringVar()
one_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=one_str)
one_entry.grid(row=2,column=0,)
two_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=two_str)
two_entry.grid(row=3,column=0)
three_entry= Entry(root)
three_entry.grid(row=4,column=0)
one_str.trace("w",update_value)
two_str.trace("w",update_value)

def update_value():
three_entry.insert(0,one_entry.get()+two_entry.get())
```

Comment: Why not attach a `StringVar` for each `Entry` you want to keep track of? Then use the `<StringVar>.trace("w", <function>)` method to tell `tkinter` call your function each time the entry gets modified. In that function, you can do the summing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, i tried to do it like that, tried a simple example with 2 entry and the 2 stringvar() each time i change either box i wanted to update a third box with the sum of the two. but just nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def update_value(*args):
    # Delete whatever is in the entry
    three_entry.delete(0, "end")
    try:
        # Compute the new data
        new_data = int(one_entry.get()) + int(two_entry.get())
        # Put the new data in the entry
        three_entry.insert(0, new_data)
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError, one or both of the entries aren't integers")

root = tk.Tk()

one_str = tk.StringVar()
one_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=one_str)
one_entry.grid(row=2,column=0,)

two_str = tk.StringVar()
two_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=two_str)
two_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)

three_entry= tk.Entry(root)
three_entry.grid(row=4, column=0)

# each time `one_str` or `two_str` is modified call `update_value`
one_str.trace("w", update_value)
two_str.trace("w", update_value)

root.mainloop()
```

It uses `.trace` to call `update_value` each time one of the 2 entries is changed. Inside `update_value`, I try to add the contents of `one_entry` and `two_entry` as `int`egers and I put that inside `three_entry`. For more info on how `.trace` works, look [here](https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-StringVar.php).

Comment: really appreciated, this helped me much more with going with a try except method. BUT still when ever one of the two entries is empty and one is not and the funciton sums them there will be a Error all the time like: one_entry with value 10 and two_entry which is empty so 10 + "" and an Error comes up. I just used pass and i think its fine but still i think an Error would come up all the time.

Comment: @Fabian28 Why not add an `if` statement to check if one of the 2 entries is empty? The code I wrote is just a toy example of how to modify an entry (`three_entry`) when another one is changed (`one_entry` or `two_entry`). You can change the function however you like.